# Create relationship between nodes based on Jaccard similarity of the nodes attributes in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, graph-data-science

I have multiple nodes in my Neo4j graph.
I want to create relationship between any 2 nodes, if and only if, their Jaccard similarity on their attributes is above some threshold alpha.

Consider 2 nodes:

```
Node 1: {id:1, abc: 1.1, eww: -9.4, ssv: "likj"}
Node 2: {id:2, we2: 1, eww: 900}
Node 3: {id:3, kuku: -91, lulu: 383, ssv: "bubu"}
```

So Node1 and Node2 Jaccard similarity on their attributes would be:
(intersection =) 2/ (union =) 5 = 0.4

How can I do this in Neo4j? I know there is a Jaccard similarity function, but how to config it to work on the attributes of the nodes?

Comment: Just for clarity, you mean the Jaccard similarity based on the presence of those attributes, not their values, right?

Comment: @SimonThordal yep, I need the Jaccard similarity on the attributes and if it's above a threshold then draw a relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the Jaccard similarity of the presence of properties then you could do something like this

```
MATCH (a:Node)
MATCH (b:Node) WHERE id(b) > id(a)
WITH a, b, [prop IN keys(a) WHERE prop IN keys(b)] AS shared_properties // Find the properties that exist on both nodes using the IN operator
WITH a, b, size(shared_properties) AS shared_property_count // Get the number of shared properties 
WITH 1.0*shared_property_count / size(apoc.coll.union(keys(a), keys(b))) AS jaccard_similarity, a, b // Compute the Jaccard similarity as the intersection over the union
WHERE jaccard_similarity > $threshold // Make sure the similarity is higher than some threshold
CREATE (a)-[:SIMILAR_TO {jaccard: jaccard_similarity}]->(b)
```

The `WITH` statements find the properties that are present on both nodes and counts them and in the end we find the Jaccard similarity.

Comment: I have tried it but it didn't work for me, trying to play with it.
Can you please explain the solution?

Comment: I've added a few explanatory comments. In what way doesn't it work at the moment?

Comment: Why in ```WITH 1.0*shared_property_count / size(keys(a)) AS jaccard_similarity, a, b // Compute the Jaccard similarity as the intersection over the union``` you don't apply union on keys of a and b nodes? In Jaccard it's union of a and b nodes attributes. @simon-thordal

Comment: And why do it's ```AS jaccard_similarity, a, b``` why ```a```, ```b```?

Comment: You're right about the union, I was missing that. It is easy enough to fix, you can get a list of the properties on both as `keys(a) + keys(b)` and you will just need to make that list unique

Comment: The reason we're carrying over the `a, b` in the `WITH` statement is so that we can create the relationship on the last line. If we didn't the variables would go out of scope.

Comment: Isn't there any builtin APOC function to do this for every 2 nodes in the graph?
It seems like classical function to be there.